# How to check a bs4 element's type with if in Python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, variable-types

When I check the `type()` of a BeautifulSoup element, it prints `<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>`.

How do I check if a variable's type is of `<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>` using `if`?

I tried both of the below methods, but it never worked even though the type of the `bs4_element_var` is `bs4.element.Tag`.

```
if type(bs4_element_var) == bs4.element.Tag:
    print("bs4_element_var's type is bs4.element.Tag")

if isinstance(bs4_element_var, bs4.element.Tag)
    print("bs4_element_var's type is bs4.element.Tag")
```

Comment: Use `isinstance()` https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance

Comment: @Iain I already tried "isinstance(bs4_element_var, bs4.element.Tag)" but there's no True or False value returned. Did I use the isinstance() function wrong?

Comment: isinstance always returns True or False (or raises a TypeError) how are you using it? Should be something like `if isinstance(bs4_element_var, bs4.element.Tag):`

Comment: @Iain I put the code in try-except and it turns out I only imported BeautifulSoup from bs4 so "name bs4 is not defined" error message was raised. It works when I import the whole bs4 package. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to also import the `Tag` together with `BeautifulSoup`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag
```

and check if your elements is of `type()` `Tag`:

```
if type(bs4_element_var) == Tag:
    print("bs4_element_var's type is bs4.element.Tag")

if isinstance(bs4_element_var, Tag):
    print("bs4_element_var's type is bs4.element.Tag")
```